# ArgumentError in Devise::Registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

> **Note:** ruby 2.3.0, Rails 5.0.0.1, devise (4.2.0)

**views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

**application trace**

```
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__2494954624473792684_38973380'
```

**full trace**

```
breach-mitigation-rails (0.2.2) lib/breach_mitigation/railtie.rb:30:in `form_authenticity_token'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:68:in `form_authenticity_token'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:589:in `token_tag'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:866:in `extra_tags_for_form'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:886:in `form_tag_html'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:891:in `form_tag_with_body'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:454:in `form_for'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/simple_form-5fcefffdadd6/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:26:in `block in simple_form_for'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/simple_form-5fcefffdadd6/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:45:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/simple_form-5fcefffdadd6/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:25:in `simple_form_for'
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb__2494954624473792684_38973380'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
```

**Rake routes output**

```
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
             user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
         new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                           PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                           PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
         user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
     new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
                           PATCH    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                           PUT      /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                           DELETE   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
         user_confirmation POST     /users/confirmation(.:format)                                                            devise/confirmations#create
     new_user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                                                        devise/confirmations#new
                           GET      /users/confirmation(.:format)                                                            devise/confirmations#show
                   sign_in GET      /sign_in(.:format)                                                                       devise/sessions#new
                           GET      /sign-in(.:format)                                                                       devise/sessions#new
                   sign_up GET      /sign_up(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#new
                           GET      /sign-up(.:format)                                                                       devise/registrations#new
```

**Full error**

```
ArgumentError in Devise::Registrations#new wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

I upgraded rails to 5 and this appears Please help me to sort it out Thanx :)

**updated views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.text_field :email, :autofocus => true, :input_html => { :autocomplete => "off" } %>
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of `simple_form_for` try `form_for`...

Comment: change the error `undefined method 'error_notification'`

Comment: Is this the error message that you are getting..?

Comment: registration_path(resource_name) why are u passing resource_name here

Comment: @rohankharvi this(registration_path(resource_name)) is generated by devise by default.

Comment: @BalaKarthik after implementing your solution i get this on the very next line if you want i can share the full error

Comment: try `<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 2):

Update

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

with

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: @ZainAbbas: Please check above answer

Comment: `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` :(

Comment: @ZainAbbas: Try now

Answer (score 2):

**According to your routes, you have**,

**`user_registration POST /users(.:format)`**

This will **`post`** to **`/users`** which is the **`create`** action for the **`registration`**.

so the form should be.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <%= f.text_field :email %>
<%end %>
```

Comment: @Zain Abbas, check this answer.

Comment: undefined method 'error_notification'     `<% resource.subscribe = true if resource.subscribe.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :autofocus => true, :input_html => { :autocomplete => "off" } %>`

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: did you set `error_notification` from the controller?

Comment: remove, <%= f.error_notification %> and add `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`

Comment: f.something supported by simple_form_for when i use form_for its starting giving errors on each line .. after replacing ` <%= f.error_notification %> to <%= devise_error_messages! %>` now its saying `undefined method 'input'   <%= f.input :email, :autofocus => true, :input_html => { :autocomplete => "off" } %>`

Comment: yes after changing to `form_for`, `simple_form_for` inputs don't work, change `input` to `text_field`

Comment: check my updated answer. you can do something like that.

Comment: After updating all the attributes ... now its giving the original error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` :(

Comment: question is updated the the current code please review

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129440/discussion-between-sravan-and-zain-abbas).